# What properties are preserved by quasi-isometries

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, geometric-group-theory, metric-spaces

Recently, I came across the notion of [quasi-isometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry), while thinking of *"discrete* spaces which are surrogates for approximate continuous ones".

What (metric)/geometric properties are preserved by quasi-isometries?  Also, are there good references on the topic?

---

**Direction/Angle:** Concretely, as an example of the direction I'm thinking in, I am interested in graph approximations to compact smooth manifolds (e.g. [in this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288909/does-there-exist-a-notion-of-discrete-riemannian-metric-on-graph)).  In that post, the described graphs are quasi-isometrically embedded into the target manifolds.

Comment: This is a very broad question... and at the same time I don't really see how the linked post is related to the question.

Comment: Ah the graph is quasi symmetrically embedded into that manifold.

Comment: If you're interested in "graph approximations to compact smooth manifolds", then I'm not certain that quasi-isometries (or, at least, much of the literature on them) is going to be relevant to you. Every compact smooth manifold is quasi-isometric to a point. What is true is that, if you want to approximate a compact manifold by a fine graph "mesh", then the *quality* of a $(\lambda,\epsilon)$-quasi-isometry will improve as the mesh gets finer -- that is, $(\lambda,\epsilon)\to (1,0)$. So the quality of the quasi-isometry should be important in your setting.

Comment: @HJRW Yes indeed, I am most curious about some quasi-isometries with minimal distortion ($\lambda$) small $\epsilon$ quasi-isometric. Thanks for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can think of quasi-isometric spaces as spaces which look the same when seen from far away. Examples of properties preserved under quasi-isometries are for example Gromov-hyperbolicity (for geodesic metric spaces), growth types of Dehn functions and various notions of "rank". As a reference I would recommend Buyalo-Schroeder: *Elements of Asymptotic Geometry*, Bridson-Haefliger: *Metric spaces of non-positive curvature* and Burago-Burago-Ivanov: *A course in metric spaces*.